# This code is not working

Tags: java, arrays

When I type this code I get answer as 58.18

```
public class text {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Data Array
        double data[]={19.2,22.3,32.51,39,41.16,49.46,55.91,58.18};

        //Finding minimum angle
        double minimum_angle=0;
        for(int counter=0;counter<data.length;counter++){

          if(data[counter]<data[counter++]){
              minimum_angle=data[counter];
          }
          else {minimum_angle=data[counter++];}
        }
        System.out.print(minimum_angle);




    }

}
```

But when I type the same with a little modification I get 55.91. Why is it so?

```
public class Main_class {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Data Array
        double data[]={19.2,22.3,32.51,39,41.16,49.46,55.91,58.18};

        //Finding minimum angle
        double minimum_angle=0;
        for(int counter=0;counter<data.length;counter++){
            double x=data[counter];
            double y=data[counter++];
          if(x<y){
              minimum_angle=x;
          }
          else {
              minimum_angle=y;
          }
        }
        System.out.print(minimum_angle);
    }
```

Comment: 1) You're clearly lying: the code *is* working. 2) What is the "little difference"? Don't make your audience comb through your code.

Comment: If you call `counter++` twice, you increase `counter` by two

Comment: It's so because your algorithm doesn't do what it's supposed to do. Stop using ++. Stop comparing an element with the next one. Compare each element to the current minimum.

Comment: Your comparison seems to be wrong. You compare the current value with the next value. But you want to find the minimum angle, don't you? So compare `data[counter]` with `minimum_angle`.

Comment: https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/find-smallest-number-in-an-array-using-java.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your snippets are incorrect.

You are misusing the post increment operator.

```
if(data[counter]<data[counter++])
```

will never be true, just like

```
if(data[counter]<data[counter])
```

will never be true.

The post increment operator returns the original value of the incremented variable.

It's not clear why you are incrementing counter in the loop body anyway. You should only increment it in the for statement. And in order to find the minimum, you must compare `data[counter]` to `minimum_angle`:

```
double minimum_angle = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for(int counter = 0; counter < data.length; counter++) {
    if(data[counter] < minimum_angle) {
        minimum_angle = data[counter];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class text {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Data Array
    double data[] = {19.2,22.3,32.51,39,41.16,49.46,55.91,58.18};

    //Finding minimum angle
    double minimum_angle = data[0];
    for(int counter = 1;counter < data.length;counter ++){

      if(minimum_angle < data[counter]){
          minimum_angle = data[counter];
      }
    }
    System.out.print(minimum_angle);




}

}
```

Initialize minimum_angle with data[0] and compare minimum_angle with data array from index 1. If minimum_angle is less than data[index] value then assign minimum_angle to data[index] to obtain minimum double value from an array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are new to programming. 
Anyway try the code below.

```
    double data[]={19.2,22.3,32.51,39,41.16,49.46,55.91,58.18};

    double minimum_angle=data[0];
    for(int counter=0;counter<data.length;counter++)
        if(minimum_angle < data[counter])
            minimum_angle = data[counter];

    System.out.print(minimum_angle);
```

Comment: Looks like you are new to Stack Overflow. Fixing OP's code without a word of explanation or explaining what they did incorrectly (especially in a question like this) is not considered a good answer.

Comment: There were many mistakes, so i dint explained. But from next time if i answer i will give with an explanation. Thank you.